# jquery span after first space

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I have three words I would like to add a span around the content after the first space so

```
hello world
```

becomes:

```
hello <span>world</span>
```

and:

```
hello world again
```

becomes:

```
hello <span>world again</span>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
 $( "#main-nav li a" ).each(function( index ) {
   $(this).html( $(this).text().replace(/([\S]*)\s(.*)/, "$1 <span>$2</span>") );
});
```

Comment: From where these words are coming? Can you show us the code for better understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with some regex:

```
text = text.replace(/([\S]*)\s(.*)/, "$1 <span>$2</span>");
```

If `text` is `hello world`, the above code will convert it to `hello <span>world</span>`

Comment: @sQVe - You're right. Didn't notice that! hmm.. It is matching the last `\s` only!

Comment: `\S` (all except `\s`) for the first match works fine too. See my edit.

Comment: `text = text.replace(/(.\s)+(.*)/, "$1<span>$2</span>");` is the cleanest solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more understandable (for me for sure),

1. use find method on whitespace character, get first position in string.
2. get first substring, from index 0 to the specific position.
3. get substring from specific position to string.length and wrap them
4. merge both strings one more time.