# How to replace the first space found with a br?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I got a string

```
Hello/Greetings My name is Rolf
```

HTML Version

```
<ul class="options-list"><li><span class="label"><label for="options_168_1">Hello/Greetings My name is Rolf </label></span></li></ul>
```

What I want to do is to add a break after frist space is found (right after **Hello/Greetings**) OR enclose "Hello/Greetings" in  tags...

The only solution for me is JS or some hacks (if their are any) CSS (didn't find any that could help me)...

How can this one be accomplished by jQuery?

Comment: Great solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427159/jquery-span-after-first-space

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do it to all labels, you can do something like this:

```js
$("label").each(function(){
  var $elem = $(this);
  $elem.html($elem.text().replace(' ','<br/>'));
});
```

Otherwise I would give the label an id and do something like this:

```js
var $elem = $('#myLabel');
$elem.html($elem.text().replace(' ','<br/>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'Hello/Greetings My name is Rolf';
str.replace(/\s/,'<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to access the text contained inside  the `<span>` with the `class="label"`, you can have that by using jQuery like this:

```
$('span.label').text()
```

But since a `class` does not target one element, like you can do with an `id`, we need to be more specific. As we can see it in your snippet the `span` element is inside a `<li>`, with the same logic we have:

```
$('li span.label').text()
```

But that's not specific enough let's take into account the `<ul>` element with the `class="options-list"`, that gives us:

```
$('ul.options-list li span.label').text()
```

Now you want to replace the first ' ' (space char) that you find in the said text by the `<br>` html element, to do that simply use:

```
$('ul.options-list li span.label').text().replace(" ", "<br />")
```

And now to use the result of that replace, and since it's html not just plain text, we need to use the `html()` function like this:

```
$('ul.options-list li span.label').html($('ul.options-list li span.label').text().replace(" ", "<br />"));
```

**But** take into account that it does not replace ***that*** space specifically, since there is no `id`, there is nothing about it that allows us to pinpoint that specific `span` element in the DOM, so what this means is that, if you want to make that change specific to that space in that specific `<span>` you need to use an `id`

```
<span id="label">blablabla second line</span>
```

and then you can use this, much cleaner, jQuery code:

```
$('#label').html($('#label').text().replace(" ", "<br />"));
```

but beware : an id can only appear one time in your DOM; it's **unique**

But if you don't want, or can't use, an `id` then the jQuery I gave you before will replace the first space found in all the `<ul class="options-list"><li><span class="label"> ... </ul>` in your DOM.

Hope it's clear enough :)

Comment: It may be useful to add an explanation of what the statement does and why you've done it that way. It often makes it clearer to the questioner and in turn helps your answer get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but it does the job:

```
var str = "Hello/Greetings My name is Rolf";
var brPos = str.indexOf(" ");

str = str.substr(0, 15) + "<br>" + str.substr(16, str.length);
```